# "new string" throws out of memory exception

Tags: c#, memory-management, out-of-memory

Can anyone help ?
While using xml serialization I experience out of memory exceptions, while trying to allocate huge memory blocks, for example with "new string( <170MB> )"

This is my test program, it shows the allocation problem:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace Out_of_memory_Exception
{

class Program
{
    static Encoding MyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
    static string Position = "";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Out of memory Exception-Test:");

        const int MEGABYTE = 1024*1024;
        for(long i=10*MEGABYTE; ; i+=10*MEGABYTE)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Console.Write("{0} MB: ", i/(1024*1024));
                Test(i);
                System.Console.WriteLine("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("{0} at {1}", ex.GetType().ToString(), Position);
            }
            if (i > (1000*MEGABYTE))
                i = 10*MEGABYTE;
        }
    }

    static void Test(long i)
    {
        Position = "new byte[i]";
        byte[] Bytes = new byte[i];

        Position = "Encoding.GetChars()";
        char[] Chars = MyEncoding.GetChars(Bytes);

        Position = "new string()";
        string s = new string(Chars);
    }
}
}
```

On my box, from 10 to 140 Megabytes all is ok, above that limit my "new string" throws an out of memory exception.

Why?

Comment: Can't you serialize to filestream instead of memorystream? That way you're only limited by allocated disk quota. Just keep the file reference around until you can dispose of it.

Comment: You should see if you can serialize in smaller pieces, e.g. by using a `Stream` you shouldn't have to load the whole thing in memory at once.

Comment: I am really surprised that this question has down votes without any reasons specified, this is a very real and genuine issue, anyone who is trying to code their own serialization will come across this issue, at the least they will have to consider this scenario

Answer (score 1):

You are exhausting memory. Perhaps you have not allocated all available memory, but the process virtual address space has been fragmented by this program. And eventually the allocator is not able to find a contiguous block of memory to satisfy your allocation request.

You solution will be one of the following:

1. Allocate less memory, that is reduce demand.
2. Switch to a 64 bit process and a bigger box, that is increase supply.
3. Allocate memory in smaller chunks, that is reduce fragmentation.

Note also that your test allocates strings that take up twice as much space as you think. Your byte arrays are treated as ANSI and converted to UTF-16. That widens from 8-bit elements to 16-bit elements.

Comment: But it's a little bit strange. You should be able to allocate huge memory blocks with the CLR. My attempts with the GC class, to tell the gargabe collector to dump all unused blocks weren't successful at all.

Comment: Your access patterns lead to fragmentation of the virtual address space. In order to allocate large blocks there must be both memory available, and contiguous address space. You've punched holes right across the address space.

Comment: Do also note that your strings are twice as big as you think.